# Set return (exit) code in find, while loop

Tags: bash, variables, loops, global-variables, exit-code

I have something like this:

```
find $1 | grep -E $2  | while read prom; do
            if [[ $prom =~ (cmd-given) ]];
            then
                ...
                RETURN_PATH=$PWD
                cd $WORKING_PATH
                ...
                if [[ -s "stdout-delta" ]] || [[ -s "stderr-delta" ]] || [[ -s "status-delta" ]];
                then
                    RET_ERROR=1
                    RESULT="FAILED"
                else
                    RESULT="OK"
                fi
                ...
                echo "$TEST: $RESULT\n" > /dev/stderr
                cd $RETURN_PATH
            fi
        done
```

I want to make test if in every folder that have cmd-given check for empty files x-delta. If any of these files is not empty I want to write FAILED and set return code to 1. But I want to check all folders so I think that I use variable, set it to 1 and at the end check if it is equal to 1 that exit 1 else exit 0. But there is problem, when I get out from that loop, I don´t have 1 in my variable. So how should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop runs in a subprocess, so you would have to use some form of IPC to communicate with the original process (the shell).

The easiest solution is probably to just echo your error message to stdout and add a pipe after the while loop to parse the output. A simple grep should suffice. Just make sure no other command can write 'FAILED' to stdout.

```
find $1 | grep -E $2  | while read prom; do
            if [[ $prom =~ (cmd-given) ]];
            then
                ...
                RETURN_PATH=$PWD
                cd $WORKING_PATH
                ...
                if [[ -s "stdout-delta" ]] || [[ -s "stderr-delta" ]] || [[ -s "status-delta" ]];
                then
                    RET_ERROR=1
                    RESULT="FAILED"
                    echo $RESULT
                else
                    RESULT="OK"
                fi
                ...
                echo "$TEST: $RESULT\n" > /dev/stderr
                cd $RETURN_PATH
            fi
        done | grep -q FAILED
[ "$?" == 0 ] && exit 1
```

Edit: temporary file based solution:

```
TMPFILE=$0.tmp
trap "rm -f $TMPFILE; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
find $1 | grep -E $2  | while read prom; do
            if [[ $prom =~ (cmd-given) ]];
            then
                ...
                RETURN_PATH=$PWD
                cd $WORKING_PATH
                ...
                if [[ -s "stdout-delta" ]] || [[ -s "stderr-delta" ]] || [[ -s "status-delta" ]];
                then
                    RET_ERROR=1
                    RESULT="FAILED"
                    echo $RESULT >> $TMPFILE
                else
                    RESULT="OK"
                fi
                ...
                echo "$TEST: $RESULT\n" > /dev/stderr
                cd $RETURN_PATH
            fi
        done

grep -q FAILED $TMPFILE && rm $TMPFILE && exit 1
rm $TMPFILE && exit 0
```

Edit 2: function based solution

```
process () {
    find $1 | grep -E $2 | (cat; echo EXIT_MARKER) | while read prom; do
            [[ $prom == "EXIT_MARKER" ]] && exit $EXIT_STATUS
            if [[ $prom =~ (cmd-given) ]];
            then
                ...
                RETURN_PATH=$PWD
                cd $WORKING_PATH
                ...
                if [[ -s "stdout-delta" ]] || [[ -s "stderr-delta" ]] || [[ -s "status-delta" ]];
                then
                    RET_ERROR=1
                    RESULT="FAILED"
                    EXIT_STATUS=1
                else
                    RESULT="OK"
                fi
                ...
                echo "$TEST: $RESULT\n" > /dev/stderr
                cd $RETURN_PATH
            fi
        done
    exit 0
}

process $1 $2
exit $?
```

Comment: I understand your solution but there would be problem that I am using echo for writing which test was get and with which result so I can´t use it just for error code. I know in my code I echo to stderr but I need a solution when echo "$TEST..." go to stdout.

Comment: The grep at the end will return TRUE if *any* of the lines printed contain "FAILED" anywhere. So if I understood correctly it should still work even when echoing all sorts of stuff to stdout; provided there aren't any undesired "FAILED" strings there.

Comment: This is what I need, I like it but I have problem that grep is always returning 1 in $?. I doesn´t matter if there is "FAILED" anywhere it always return 1.

Comment: My mistake there. Please try again with the new version (the last line changed).

Comment: Now it´s working perfect but that´s one part for output to /dev/stderr and I need when change parametr that it should echo `"$TEST: $RESULT\n" > /dev/stdout` but grep is taking all stdout. So final thing, how you change it for that?

Comment: Ah, that makes it harder. The easiest alternative in this case is to just use a temp file, I think. Please see my edited answer. You can also use `mktemp` to create a better tempfile (randomized name, located in `/tmp`).

Comment: +1 for the correct basic diagnosis (sub-process).  Note that you should ensure that the temp file is cleaned up with `trap "rm -f $TMPFILE; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15` before you create it and `trap 0` before you exit.  This is doubly important with randomized names; it is hard to associate random names with the process that created them, making clean-up more difficult.  Also, `cd /some/where; ...; cd /where/it/started` is usually not a good idea; I prefer to run a sub-shell.  However, that probably just compounds the problems here.

Comment: This is just little part of my project and I forget mention that I can´t create any temp file :/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you're right about the trap, thanks. But wouldn't `trap 0` force an `exit 1` everytime then?

Comment: @Bibo: can you call exit from within the while loop? Calling exit just before exiting the loop would fix things, provided you can identify the last line somehow.

Comment: @Bibo: alternatively, you may want to convert your loop to a function and `exit` a flag value. That should let you use this approach even when you have to do extra processing after the while loop.

Comment: I just don´t know which loop whould be the last so I can´t call exit from loop. How do you convert loop to a function?

Comment: The final `trap 0` clears the trap on exit so that you can exit with whatever status you like.  In the initial trap setting, the `trap "rm -f $TMPFILE; exit 1" 0 ...` ensures that if the shell exits for any reason, the file is removed and there's an exit status of 1 (failure).  You can omit that if you like; I use it along with the given signal list (HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE and TERM).  If someone sends my shell a SIGIOT or SIGFPE, I'm willing to leave the file behind.

Comment: @Bibo: see my latest edit, I added the function. Note I also added an EXIT_MARKER to the output before passing it to the while loop; that allows you to detect the last line and exit accordingly.

Comment: I just don´t know how to do that. Very helpful with that cat and EXIT_STATUS. Thank you very much and sorry for all that trouble.

Comment: P.s.: Just thinking that last exit 0 there shouldn´t be (for me working without that).